# OpenMP with Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: g++, openmp

I encountered a problem when using OpenMP to parallelize my code. I have attached the simplest code that can reproduce my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int size = 1;

    vector<double> vec(1, double(1.0));
    double sum = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for private(vec) reduction(+: sum)
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        /* in real case, complex operations applied on vec here */

        sum += vec[0];
    }

    cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with g++ with flag -fopenmp, and the error message from g++ prompts "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I am wondering what's wrong with the code.

Note that `vec` should be set to private since in the real code a complex operation is applied on `vec` in the for-loop.

Comment: I can change  `cout` to any other operation on `vec[0]`, but the bug still exists. The problem comes from the `vector` object in my opinion.

Comment: In order not to digress, I changed a bit of my code and replaced `cout` with a summation in the parallel block. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem indeed comes from the `private(vec)` clause.  There are two issues with this code.

First, from a semantics perspective, the `private(vec)` should be `shared(vec)`, as the intent seems to be to work on the same `std::vector` instance in parallel.  So, the code should look like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(vec), reduction(+: sum)
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
{
    sum += vec[0];
}
```

In the previous code, the `private(vec)` made a private instance of `std::vector` for each thread and was supposed to initialize these instances by calling the default constructor of `std::vector`.

Second, the segmentation fault then arises from the fact that there's no `vec[0]` element in any of the private instances.  This can be confirmed by calling `vec.size()` fro the threads.

PS: `shared(vec)` would be been the default sharing for `vec` as per the OpenMP specification anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `vec` is intended to be a private variable since in a real case, complex operations should be applied on `vec`. Anyhow, you answered my question since OpenMP initializes the `vec` object with the default constructor with zero length so that cause the segmentation fault error. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you need private instances of `std::vector`, then you might consider `firstprivate(vec)`, but then you'll get a copy constructed copy of the original vector for each thread.  Because I do not know what you're trying to achieve, I'm not sure if that's going to work out for you in the end.